# C—Infinite loop, I think?

Tags: c, arrays, function, loops, infinite-loop

I'm having an issue with a program in C and I think that a `for` loop is the culprit, but I'm not certain. The function is meant to take a `char[]` that has already been passed through a reverse function, and write it into a different `char[]` with all trailing white space characters removed. That is to say, any `' '` or `'\t'` characters that lie between a `'\n'` and any other character shouldn't be part of the output.

It works perfectly if there are no trailing white space characters, as in re-writing an exact duplicate of the input `char[]`. However, if there are any, there is no output at all.

The program is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 1000

void trim(char output[], char input[], int len);
void reverse(char output[], char input[], int len);

main()
{
    int i, c;
    int len;

    char block[MAXLINE];
    char blockrev[MAXLINE];
    char blockout[MAXLINE];
    char blockprint[MAXLINE];

    i = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        block[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }

    printf("%s", block); // for debugging purposes
    reverse(blockrev, block, i); // reverses block for trim function
    trim(blockout, blockrev, i);
    reverse(blockprint, blockout, i); // reverses it back to normal
    // i also have a sneaking suspicion that i don't need this many arrays?
    printf("%s", blockprint);
}

void trim(char output[], char input[], int len)
{
    int i, j;

    i = 0;
    j = 0;

    while (i <= len)
    {
        if (input[i] == ' ' || input[i] == '\t')
        {
            if (i > 0 && input[i-1] == '\n')
                for (; input[i] == ' ' || input[i] == '\t'; ++i)
                {

                }
            else
            {
                output[j] = input[i];
                ++i;
                ++j;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            output[j] = input[i];
            ++i;
            ++j;
        }
    }
}

void reverse(char output[], char input[], int len)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; len - i >= 0; ++i)
    {
        output[i] = input[len - i];
    }
}
```

I should note that this is a class assignment that doesn't allow the use of string functions, hence why it's so roundabout.

Comment: This is why I like the stile where matching brackets are in the same column

Comment: Or just any consistent indentation style.. It looks like you have `while/else` here at first.

Comment: Sort out the indentation - then might be able to spot the problem. Have you considered using a debugger?

Comment: Cleaned it up a little bit. Sorry, this is only my second post and I'm a total C newbie. It should be a lot easier to read now, though.

Comment: are you sure you're getting an infinite loop, it looks like you'd get a segmentation fault around `for (i; input[i] == ' ' || input[i] == '\t'; ++i);`

Comment: Not completely sure, but when it happens, I don't get a segmentation fault error. The program just has nothing for output and is done.

Comment: @JazzBullets So, the program does finish, but outputs nothing? Then it's not an infinite loop (since it doesn't go on indefinitely)…

Comment: Wow, I guess that really wouldn't be infinite. More specifically, it seems to me that if there are trailing white spaces, it just increases `i` until `i > len`, then I get an empty array.

Comment: I just ran it with "`print a string.`" as input. I changed it so that it would `printf` the initial array (`char block[]`) and the resulting array after it had gone through `reverse`, `trim`, then `reverse` again. The output was
`print a string.\nprint a string.` (obviously the \n wasn't visible, though)
Then I typed "`print a string.   `" (with three spaces after the `.`) as the input, and the only output was
`print a string.   `

Comment: @JazzBullets Are you sure the problem is in this function at all? Perhaps you should edit the question to include a complete program that reproduces the error (leave out `reverse` if it's not related – or if removing `reverse` fixes the problem, then you know that your problem is there).

Comment: `reverse` functions perfectly, and the only time I have an issue is when there are white space characters between `\n` and another character. I'll edit the question, though. I've been known to miss obvious things here and there.

Comment: @JazzBullets A stab in the dark: does your `reverse` also take the length of the string as argument? If so, are you recalculating the length after `trim`, because it will be shorter in your error cases?

Comment: @Arkku It does, and I am not. This sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
for (i; input[i] == ' ' || input[i] == '\t'; ++i);
```

to

```
for (; i <= len && (input[i] == ' ' || input[i] == '\t'); ++i);
```

With the first method, if the whitespace is at the end, the loop will iterate indefinitely. Not sure how you didn't get an out of bounds access exception, but that's C/C++ for you.

**Edit** As Arkku brought up in the comments, make sure your character array is still NUL-terminated (the `\0` character), and you can check on that case instead. Make sure you're not trimming the NUL character from the end either.

Comment: Hmm, checking `len` shouldn't make a difference if `input` is NUL-terminated because the end won't match either space or tab? (Granted, the OP did not specify if `input` is a C string.)

Comment: C doesn't have runtime bounds checking. Its one of its "charms". If you are patient, you will eventually get an access violation/segmentation fault of some kind though.

Comment: @Arkku: Good point about NUL-termination. Perhaps OP didn't add the sentinel character to the array in the preprocessing reverse step either.

Comment: @Arkku - Yeah, if it really is character data, you really need to nul terminate it anyway. Its not a requirement of the language, but a whole lot of string-handling library routines (and users) will expect it. Going against the convention is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 1):

(Moved from comments to an answer)

My guess is that the problem is outside this function, and is caused by the fact that in the described problem cases the output is shorter than the input. Since you are passing the length of the string as an argument, you need to calculate the length of the string after `trim`, because it may have changed...

For instance, passing an incorrect length to `reverse` can cause the terminating NUL character (and possibly some leftover whitespace) to end up at the beginning of the string, thus making the output appear empty.

**edit**: After seeing the edited question with the code of `reverse` included, in addition to the above problem, your `reverse` puts the terminating NUL as the first character of the reversed string, which causes it to be the empty string (in some cases your second `reverse` puts it back, so you don't see it without printing the output of the first `reverse`). Note that `input[len]` contains the `'\0'`, not the last character of the string itself.

**edit 2**: Furthermore, you are not actually terminating the string in `block` before using it. It may be the case that the uninitialised array often happens to contain zeroes that serve to terminate the string, but for the program to be correct you absolutely need to terminate it with `block[i] = '\0';` immediately after the input loop. Similarly you need ensure NUL-termination of the outputs of `reverse` and `trim` (in case of `trim` it seems to me that this already happens as a side-effect of having the loop condition `i <= len` instead of `i < len`, but it's not a sign of good code that it's hard to tell).

Comment: I've changed `trim` to return an `int` equal to the length of `output`, and I'm using that number as an argument for the second instance of `reverse`. Now, it doesn't return anything at all, but I feel a lot closer to figuring this out.

Comment: @JazzBullets I would strongly recommend testing with a smaller program first, and printing your results between each step, not after it has gone through two `reverse`'s and a `trim`. As far as I can tell, `trim` is working just fine if I run the code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring your `main()` function simply as `main()` is an obsolete style that should not be used. The function must be declared either as `int main(void)` or as `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Your input process does not null-terminate your input. This means that what you're working with is not a "string", because a C string, by definition, is an array of `char` that the last element is a null character ('\0'). Instead, what you've got are simple arrays of `char`. This wouldn't be a problem as long as you're expecting that, and indeed your code is passing array lengths about, but you're also trying to print it with `printf()`, which requires C strings, not simple arrays of char.

Your `reverse()` function has an off-by-one error, because you aren't accounting for the fact that C arrays are zero-indexed, so what you're reversing is always one byte longer than your actual input.

What this means is that if you call `reverse(output, input, 10)`, your code will start by assigning the value at `input[10]` to `output[0]`, but `input[10]` is one *past* the end of your data, and since you didn't initialize your arrays before starting to fill them, that's an indeterminate value. In my testing, that indeterminate value happens, coincidentally, to have zero values much of the time, which means that `output[0]` gets filled with a null (`'\0'`).

You need to be subtracting one more from the index into the `input` than you actually are. The loop-termination condition in the `reverse()` function is also wrong, in compensation, that condition should be `len - i > 0`, not `len - i >= 0`.

Your `trim()` function is unnecessarily complex. Additionally, it too has an incorrect loop condition to compensate for the off-by-one error in `reverse()`. The loop should be `while ( i < len )`, not `while ( i <= len )`.

Additionally, the `trim()` function has the ability to reduce the size of your data, but you don't provide a way to retain that information. (I see in the comments of Arkku's answer that you've corrected for this already. Good.)

Once you've fixed the issue with not keeping track of your data's size changes, and the off-by-one error which is copying indeterminate data (which happens, coincidentally, to be a null) from the end of the `blockout` array to the beginning of the `blockprint` array when you do the second `reverse()`, and you fix the incorrect `<=` condition in `trim()` and the incorrect `>=` condition in `reverse()`, and you null-terminate your byte array before passing it to `printf()`, your program will work.

Comment: Regarding `trim`, it seems to me that the OP's loop condition `i <= len` actually has the effect of correctly NUL-terminating the output. I agree, though, that it would be better style to only iterate over the string itself and then terminate manually… (Also, I think it best to refer to the NUL character by its three-letter mnemonic, rather than as "null", due to `NULL` in C referring to a null pointer.)

Comment: Anyhow, +1 for noticing the additional problems in the OP's modified question (original question only had the `trim` function shown).

Comment: @Arkku how is it _correctly_ null-terminating the output? Where is that null coming from? (Hint: "indeterminate".)

Comment: If `input` of `trim` is terminated, and the loop is as per OP's post (i.e., `i <= len`), then the terminating NUL from `input[len]` is assigned to the end of `output` in every case as far as I can tell. (You correctly spotted that the OP's code does not deterministically terminate the string before passing it to `trim`, but if this is fixed in `main` then it seems that `trim` is correct as is, under the preconditions that it operates on C strings and `len` is the length as per `strlen`.)

Comment: @Arkku ...fine. _IF_ the string is correctly null-terminated to begin with, and _IF_ the `reverse()` function is fixed, then the incorrect loop condition in `trim()` will accidentally have the effect of null-terminating the shortened string. It's still _wrong_, though.

Comment: Well, obviously we should assume that the other code will be fixed, and since these are functions operating on C strings it should also be assumed that the strings are correctly terminated just like with any other C-string function… Anyhow, I agree that it's not good style, but it is not wrong, and if the OP changes the loop condition according to your answer it _will_ be broken because it no longer terminates the output. So, perhaps add the suggestion on how to fix that?

Comment: @Arkku I disagree. Accidentally null-terminating the modified string by virtue of an incorrect loop condition is wrong. I did already tell the poster that he needs to null-terminate on purpose, before attempting to `printf()` the string.

Comment: I honestly don't see how the loop condition is wrong if it leads to the correct behaviour with no chance of unwanted behaviour due to it. Whether the OP happened upon it by accident or by design is not a property of the code itself.

Comment: @Arkku Also, with reference to your statement about "NUL-terminating", that's also incorrect. In C, strings aren't terminating by having an ASCII `NUL` character appended, they're terminated by appending a sentinel value that the C standard explicitly names "the _null character_", which coincidentally has the same value as the ASCII `NUL` character. See N1570, section 5.2.1, paragraph 2. (The word "NUL" appears only once in N1570, in a footnote.)

Comment: @Arkku I don't see it as being the correct behavior, though. If bug number two accidentally compensates for bug number one, you don't call it "correct", you call it "disaster waiting to happen". After all, what happens when someone else on the team fixes one of the bugs?

Comment: Umm, NUL is just a mnemonic for null, and it is not by coincidence that it was chosen as the terminator, which is called the “null character” because it is _the_ null character, aka NUL. Anyhow, I didn't claim that "null character" is wrong (obviously it isn't since the NUL mnemonic comes from that name) – I've just found that in practice speaking of "null" to beginning C programmers leads to confusion between `NULL` and `'\0'`, e.g., someone told to “null terminate” may do `str[len] = NULL`.

Comment: As for the statement about bugs, I don't see what “bug number two” the loop condition in `trim` supposedly compensates for. If we take the function `trim` in isolation, it is correct for C strings as is.